# Build multiple projects at once

Tags: cmake

I have the following directory structure for my project

DroneSoftware/ (Top level folder)

- Wings/
- Propellers/
- BatteryManagement/
- RadioCommunication/
- Gyroscope/
- FlightController/

  - RaspBerryPi/
  - BeagleBone/
  - Arduino/
- testWings.cpp
- testPropellers.cpp
- testWingsPropellers.cpp
- testFlightController.cpp
- testBatteryMgmt.cpp
- testRadioComm.cpp
- testGyro.cpp

I want to build all test programs at once when I do make all.
for ex.

testWings.cpp object file should be named as testWings it will use libWings.a & libFlightController.a using code in Wings/ & FlightController/

testPropellers.cpp object file should be named as testPropeller it will use libPropellers.a & libFlightController.a using code in Propellers/ & FlightController/

and so on.

I am able to build individual projects using different CMakeLists.txt for each test program, but I want everything to be included in one file only.

please help me.

Comment: In a single `CMakeLists.txt` you could create as many libraries (`add_library`) and executables (`add_executable`) as you want. Not sure that I understand your problem.

Comment: yes I did that .. but each executables depend on different libraries how do I handle that ? This is my problem .. can you help me with that ? I guess now my problem is clear to you.

Comment: "but each executables depend on different libraries"- Just link each executable with corresponded library(ies) using `target_link_libraries`.